# Showing multiple role linkages in a single form

Tags: forms, layout, roles

Working on a form design that lets the admin manage users. Besides editing user details, they can add or remove roles, Also for each role added,  it should display the reports and forms it makes accessible to users(non-admins)

Initially, we thought the simplest way to solve this was to simply put each group of info under tabs (below), but realized it would be more useful to show the admin exactly which reports and forms each role gives users.

Are there any best practices or design patterns that would be useful for achieving this?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have already encountered this use case, and we chose to focus instead on a page that brings together the forms. The assumption was that administrators don't go to the user list to assign roles; they assign people and roles to a form rather than the other way around.

So, we have a table with all the forms, featuring mass selection options and the ability to assign users to different forms with predefined roles.

We use a "modal side-panel"

[image]

Comment: That's a nice way of looking at the problem from a different perspective.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. We're looking at a 2-way solution for this. The one you've described as well as the ability to update from the user's end.

Comment: @BlueOcean All roads lead to Rome =D

Answer (score 0):

To simplify working with detailed Roles you may create Profiles which combine typical set of Roles and assign user Profile while administering set of Roles for particular Profile.

Profile examples:

- Salesman
- Manager
- Department Manager
- Top Manager

Each Profile is administered to have particular Roles for particular Forms. As a bonus you have indirect mass permission change for each user by modifying its Profile Roles.